# If $x \in A$ is a limit point of $A$, does there always exist an $\epsilon$-nhood of $x$ for every $a \in A$ such that $a \in V_{\epsilon}(x)$?

Tags: general-topology

The definition of limit point that I'm using is:

**Definition.** A point $x$ is a *limit point* of a set $A$ if every $\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ of $x$ intersects the set $A$ in some point other than $x$.

Now, what I want to know is that, if $x \in A$ and is a limit point of $A$, is it true that: there exists an $\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ of $x$ for every $a \in A$ such that $a \in V_{\epsilon}(x)$?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but doesn't taking $\epsilon$ to be twice the distance between $a$ and $x$ suffice?

Comment: If $x$ is a limit point, we know that any neighborhood from it "hits" *some* $a\in A$. But what I really want to know is that, if I have an arbitrary $a\in A$, is there always a neighborhood of $x$ that "hits" it? I guess it's kind of confusing when the quantifiers are being juggled around.

Comment: @angryavian: Wait, I think you might be correct. This is sort of a trivial question after all.